# Firebase flutter notification onMessageOpened is not called

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification, notifications

I'm trying to setup iOS notifications in flutter project with firebase. I have

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

this in `AppDelegate` file, but still I don't receive callback to onMessageOpenedApp / getInitialMessage in iOS when notification is tapped. This works fine in Android.

I'm seeing this in logs, could this cause an issue?

```
Warning: UNUserNotificationCenter delegate received call to -userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.
```